# How to pass Parameter from My aspx Page to windows application

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have develop my software in asp.net (VS2010) and run it in IIS 7.0. I have another software in Windows application (VS2010).

When I click Button in asp.net web page, I need to run that exe file and passing parameter from web page to windows form.

1. Run exe when I click Button in aspx page
2. Pass Parameter from aspx to win form

Comment: It is design, for security that you can not run application from a webpage. If the application is already running something like a websocket between the app and the server could allow to pass information.

Answer (score 0):

the requirement is a little strange, assume your asp.net page and windows are host in same machine with propitiate privileges settings, you can achieve this by using Process Class:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Process process = new Process();
    process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\notepad.exe";
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = @"c:\windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts";
    process.Start();
}
```